# Meaning of "be of" in the given context

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> Thursday’s tragedy should serve as a grim warning to the powers that **be of** potentially darker times ahead if the surcharged rhetoric is left unchecked.

What does **be of** mean here?

Comment: Reminder: include your source (with a link if possible) and your research or understanding of the problem. This will help prevent close votes. See [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/36187) and the [Contributor's Guide (Asking)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/36187) for tips and examples.

Comment: I feel like every time there's "meaning of <phrase>" the answer ends up being "that's actually the end of one phrase and beginning of another"

Comment: @Walt Hardly every time, but commonly. And the cases where it is stand out more.

Answer (score 37):

"**The powers that be**" is a set phrase, which means:

> important people who have authority over others ([Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/powers-that-be))

So the correct parsing of the sentence should read "**the powers that be**" together. The sentence is saying that

> Thursday’s tragedy should serve as a grim **warning of potentially darker times ahead** *to the people in power* if the surcharged rhetoric is left unchecked.

As you can see, the "of" goes not with "be", but with "warning". The complement that follows "of" describes the content of the warning and tells you what is being warned. "The powers that be" is the people in power/positions of authority, and is the recipient of the warning, to whom the warning is issued.